# Division algorithm to prove finite powers of $x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $x$ is an element of finite order $n$ in group $G$, use the division algorithm to show that any integral power of $x$ is one of $\{1,x,x^2,...,x^{n-1}\}$.

I've been able to construct a proof of this without the division algorithm, but how would I use it to prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given an integer $k$, write $k=nq+r$ with $r\in \{1,2,\ldots n-1\}$.

You'll have $x^k=x^{nq}x^r=x^r\in\{1, x, \ldots , x^{n-1}\}$.

Comment: I'm kicking myself at how easy that was. Thank you